# Accented tags not displayed properly on edit page on mobile web site

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, mobile-web, localization

When editing a question with tags which contain accent marks (and likely other non-ASCII characters), the display is garbled, showing HTML escape sequences to the user:

[image]

The above screen shot is taken while editing [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16458/1064) on my Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1 viewing the mobile web site (not the Android app).  Although I initially discovered the issue trying to edit [this question](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9/22) on the pre-private-beta ES.SO (so likely not yet visible to many people).

Comment: Reproduced on iPhone 6.

Comment: Also in [es.so]. Reported in [Las etiquetas con tildes se reproducen incorrectamente en la versión móvil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2221/83).

Comment: Reproduced on Android 4.1, 4.4, 5.1 and 7.1.

Comment: @fedorqui This bug isn’t just one that affects only the sites with a fully localized GUI: tags anywhere with diacritics have this problem, so on language sites like es.SE  and pt.SE as well, not just es.SO and pt.SO &c. I hadn't noticed this before because I don't try to do much with the cell-phone app. Oddly, even the regular web site does has this same nasty bug in "mobile" mode, but if you switch it to "full site", then it works again. Mostly. I can’t get the tag editor to fire off, but you can just edit the post proper.

Comment: @tchrist yes, I have been struggling with this bug in Spanish.SE for years now. I just checked and we did not report it in our Meta yet, but it is quite uncomfortable since most of the questions have a tag with a diacritic, so editing them via mobile is quite an unpleasant user experience.

Comment: This has been fixed!

Comment: @JuanM Finally, a great job! Thanks for fixing this old, annoying bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268826/accented-tags-not-displayed-properly-on-edit-page-on-mobile-web-site?noredirect=1#comment1046013_268826) by @JuanM, and confirmed on my Pixel, this is now fixed. Thank you!

[image]