# Non-English meta and Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, meta, languages

Not speaking English should not be a reason for your concerns not being taken into account. We are probably losing a great deal of knowledge and ideas due to the language barrier.

I know there are sites in languages other than English, but what about the sites concerning the greater Stack Exchange community itself? Are there any plans to create non-English versions of Meta Stack Exchange and Area 51?

Comment: No, there are not any plans, AFAIK. Do you envision an MSE and Area51 per language? Can you elaborate where the experts come from that would provide the content that visitors are looking for on those language specific MSE and Area51?

Comment: somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/feedback-and-initiatives-on-international-sites

Comment: It *shouldn't*, but isn't it how everything works? For instance, academic works that are not in English are in a huge disadvantage. I think someone coming to participate in Stack Exchange should have already accepted that they'd need to communicate, at least sporadically, in English.

Comment: @Marshmallow I agree... but only partly. Imagine if we wanted to make a, let's say, Bullfighting Stack Exchange community. English would be a very bad language choice

Comment: @rene Of course I'm not talking about having 7000 different Meta sites, but just as 7000 is not the best number, I am pretty sure 1 is neither! I don't see what harm would there be at having a Meta site in Russian, Chinese or Spanish

Comment: @rene, participants in the meta sites of es.stackoverflow.com and spanish.stackexchange.com might contribute to es.meta.stackexchange.com; similarly for the other languages which already have multiple sites in the network.

Comment: “… *7000 different Meta sites* …” Seven thousand? Do we need this hyperbole? Plausibly, it would be around 69 (excluding French, Italian, German, and Russian) at the very most 73.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I used "7000" because that's one of the most accepted estimates of how many languages are spoken in the world

Comment: So do you think there should even be 1,000 stack exchange sites? What do you think would be a realistic number of meta sites? Or are you suggesting that each of the 173 SE sites should have 100 meta sites catering for at least 100 different languages? One hundred, not seven thousand mind you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please read again my comment on that subject, mainly the part where it reads "Of course I'm NOT talking about having 7000 different Meta sites, but just as 7000 is NOT the best number..." It seems you are struggling to understand English, which is exactly my point

Comment: Here is the Russian meta  site 1: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ 2. here is the Portuguese meta: site https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ here is the Italian meta site 3. here is the Spanish meta site: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Mari-LouA just admit you're struggling with English ... ;)

Comment: 4. Here is the Japanese meta site: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/ 5. here is the German meta site https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/ 6. Here is the French meta site https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/ **If users have questions about SE and how it is run, I do not see any reason why they cannot ask their question in any of the aforementioned sites**. Where catering for languages is concerned, I think SE is doing a pretty good job.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Those are links to the language learning meta sites, or the Stack Overflow meta sites, not the Stack Exchange meta sites

Comment: While I'm not unsympathetic to the idea of increasing inclusiveness by breaking down language barriers I try to envision how this should practically pan out. MSE is for setting network wide policies. What happens if the ch.meta.stackexchange.com reaches a different consensus on down voting. How is that then applied / communicated network wide? Same for Area 51. Can I propose an Chinese Language site for Portugese on the nl.Area51.stackexchange.com? There is too much unclear to consider the feature request in its current state.

Comment: @rene Well, if there are enough Portuguese speakers willing to learn Chinese, I don't see that as a problem. I cannot currently ask questions in Portuguese on the Chinse learning site, so why not? Similarly, I don't see any problem with different opinions on different subjects that apply on different sites. Isn't diversity our strength?

Comment: But here on MSE, this very site, we cater for all sites, network wide. On the per-site meta's local variations are vetted.

Comment: @rene Why not allow questions in any language then? When you see a question in Russian, just ignore it, like non-English speakers do with their "hot questions" list

Comment: Diversity is a strength but for a policy or site launching entity you also need enough users. We gain nothing with an A+ for inclusiveness and no content or launched sites.

Comment: @rene But now the question is: Do non-English sites fail because there are not enough people interested in them or are there not enough people interested in them because we have too few non -English sites? Try a bullfighting community, for example. Who on his right mind would use English rather than Spanish as its language?

Comment: @David that has been proposed before and has been rejected. *Just ignore it* is not what we optimize for. And I personally think we're not that dismissive on MSE when a post is lacking in grammar and spelling. If that is what drives non-native speakers away then let's address that but making this a language mess doesn't seem beneficial to greater community. Language is the least of the problems. Culture might be an bigger issue but I admit that is harder to address.

Comment: You can only know if bullfighting will fly if you propose it on A51. And you can state in the proposal that the site language will be in spanish. It won't launch for reasons beyond wanting to be inclusive but A51 is in theory not a blocking factor to create a site for a spanish speaking bullfighting community.

Comment: @rene But I have to put the proposal in English, so no people who are interested in it would even be aware of the possibility of creating the site (the number of English speaking bullfighters I've found in my life is quite low)

Comment: As I said earlier, that is true for [other reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/how-can-i-propose-a-non-english-site/53004#53004) then that [English is mandatory](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8675/non-english-proposal-requirements).

Comment: @rene OK, so then we just agree that Stack is a racist, uninclusive site. I don't have any particular problem with that as long as we say it openly and don't try to fool ourselves

Comment: Okay, I'm out of here. Good luck.

Comment: How did we get from "English language" to "racist"?  Requiring English might not be *inclusive*, but I don't see how it's *racist*.  Anyway, I suggest we back down from the accusations and hyperbole and focus on the core problem, which is how to include those not fluent in English in meta discussions that affect the whole network including the non-English parts.

Comment: This question is tagged feature-request but is asked more as a discussion question.  Which did you intend?  I think it's a fine discussion to have; FRs usually do better if they make a strong case.  (In my experience, asking for the discussion *first* and letting that inform the FR, if you decide to make an FR, works best.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Don't you see a kind of correlation between your etnicity and your language?

Answer (score 7):

> Not speaking English should not be a reason for your concerns not being taken into account.

That's true, but the problem with stating your concerns in another language than English would be that **80%-99% of the people here** (depending on the language) wouldn't be able to read, let alone *respond* to those concerns. This includes both the 'Meta crowd', who is usually able to give good feedback on concerns/ideas, and Stack Exchange employees who might need to make executive decisions. To state it differently, for effective communication we *need* a [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) and it happens to be English (which is not surprising since the network originated as a site about programming).

Note that for topics which are deemed important enough, discussion in different languages is actually facilitated (see the question @rene linked to, [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/feedback-and-initiatives-on-international-sites)) but this requires a huge effort of (volunteer) translators, and it's hard to keep track of discussions happening at multiple places simultaneously.

---

> We are probably losing a great deal of knowledge and ideas due to the language barrier.

IMHO, we might lose *some* ideas but certainly not a 'great deal'. [A little Google Translate goes a long way](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22845/glorfindel?tab=answers) - a good machine-translated proposal will get a lot more attention here than one in Spanish anywhere on the network.

I can even argue that es.meta.stackexchange.com already exists. The scope of [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com) is [not limited to Stack Overflow en español alone]:

> - ...Stack Overflow la empresa se comunique con la comunidad (pidiendo comentarios sobre nuevas ideas o funciones, o discutir políticas que afecten a *la red completa*)

([translated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta))

> - ...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect *the whole network*)

(emphasis mine)

---

> Are there any plans to create non-English versions of Meta Stack Exchange and Area 51?

No, there are no such plans. Actually, the [current policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53004/295232) is to not add any non-English sites *at all*:

> Update: As of 2015, we are not currently accepting proposals for non-English sites. This is because launching and supporting a non-English site requires a lot of support, from localizing the entire user interface to hiring a community manager that speaks the language in question. Overall, supporting many non-English sites will not be sustainable given the current administrative state.

Comment: That's just shameful! And also quite racist! Maybe the reason why "80%-99% of the people here" will not be able to understand those discussions is precisely the English-langauge focus of the platform

Comment: What exactly is shameful/racist? I've tried to word my post as objectively and 'neutrally' as I can, but I'm open to improvements ...

Comment: I am not talking about the post, but about the policy

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: There are far more than 1% of users who can speak more than one language. 80% monolingual users seems to be a better guess.

Comment: @Mari-LouA correct; what I meant is that if I post something in Dutch, 99% of the users won't be able to read it (without Google Translate). In Spanish or Chinese, it might be 80%. With English, I'm sure 99% of the network *will* be able to read it.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. There a few Dutch users. Cerberus and rene (I think) a few who come to mind, not to mention those who lurk. And...in my limited experience, Dutch people tend to have excellent English skills.

Answer (score 6):

Well, MSE is a bit of a special case: the "language" metas, for the most part, should cover their own languages. MSE's kind of the prototype for *all* the metas, with their own quirks. In many cases, unless it's a network wide issue, a local meta would be your first port of call, even on English sites.

If you *do* have a language site *with* a specific problem you can't solve on your meta, *someone's* gotta be able to write English. Work it out on your meta, mug a mod or a trusted bilingual, and get them to bring it up. If it's a broader issue not local to your site, it's still OK here.

*If you have an actual problem, someone will help*. We'll just have to work together to find the best way to bridge that language gap.

From the perspective of a long time user of the network (and a moderator): each additional language has tended to need a fair bit of additional resources - and is pretty intensive compared to a regular site. Each language had a native or semi-native language-speaking CM (though, for the most part, those got rolled into the main CM pool). I think there's *about* 11 CMs, and having four CMs specifically for languages ended up not working that well. We do still have a few native language-speaking CMs (and one person whose exact role is a mystery covering a site) for the non-English sites. Diversity is awesome, but even if we had one CM per language, about a third of the team or more would be covering one site each.

There's cultural communication: stuff sometimes would get lost in translation, even between different dialects of the same language... If there's a critical issue on the site, it's going to be tricky getting someone up to speed and looking at it.

Well, at least at the moment, I don't think Stack Overflow (the company) has the resources and willpower to do it for now.

I suppose that *could* change if a new language worked with the company's bigger goals. The language SOs were when folks were pushing for SO to grow, and felt those developer communities were underserved. SE's kinda in a bit of flux, and has been for a while.

Comment: But there is no need for a CMs being natives! Why not hire a couple of people who speak a lot of languages each?

Comment: Polygots don't exactly grow on trees - and well, honestly, looking at the current state of SE, I'd rather have more resources for the 170 or so sites over hiring folks for maybe 2-3 sites that may or may not work.

Comment: They actually do! The problem is that this is too America-focused, where nobody is a polyglot. More than a billion people in the world speak 3 or more languages

Answer (score 1):

## Tl;Dr

The key success factor for a feature request like this one is to have already a community around the topic in focus that is willing to have Q/A site based on the SE Network model.

Many proposals failed (were rejected) because the community didn't exist on before hand.

---

This isn't straight forward but I think that it's a good workaround for asking a question about the SE Network:

If a user speaks  Esperanto, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Latin, Portuguese, Spanish, Russian, Ukrainian, ... and they are not able to post their question about the SE Network on the a Meta site that use one of those languages, they could post their question on the main sites and it will later be migrated to the corresponding Meta. Then if the topic should be escalated a local moderator will do this and if if someone else that speaks the local language and English thinks that the topic is of interest of the audience of Meta SE they will do the translation / adaptation and post it here.

Regarding Area 51, the last time I look at this, they weren't accepting requests for new International sites.

If you are interested on proposing a new SE network site where there are already a community were most of the members don't speak English that could make things harder but not impossible, I think.

1. You should have to "recruit" a certain number of community members that speak English and that are willing to serve as "liaison officers"
2. You should accept to use English as the main language and as the language of the UI.
3. You have to argue why it's important to allow questions on a different language in similar way that it's done on language learning sites and convince the Area 51 CM that it is a good idea.

Comment: Let me add that the other way around is also possible. I had seen a meta post on one of the russian meta sites which I could provide an answer for. I left a comment in English first, asking if an English answer would be appreciated (as I don't speak, write or understand Russian). After that I posted my answer in English that was later in a few edits translated to Russian.

Comment: @rene Another example of that is that the International Sites CM doesn't speaks Spanish so he post in English and someone translate it to the local language.